# Where is the definition of the derivative formula derived from?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, math-history

I know what the definition of the derivative is , however, I am curious where this comes from mathematically.

Comment: you mean who first introduced the concept?

Comment: If we consider the derivative as the slope of the tangent line at a point on a curve, then it stems from limiting the slope of a secant line passing through that point. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Slope of the tangent line; remember the old slope formula where $m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$?  Consider a secant line whose two points are getting closer and closer...this will more resemble the tangent as the points get closer and closer...

Comment: The derivative is the rate of change (i.e. slope) of a function at a point.  See [this image](http://www.thecalculuspage.com/images/animationgraphicderivativeforpp.gif).  Notice that for large $h$, the difference quotient is not a very good approximation of the slope of the tangent line -- but it gets better and better as $h$ gets smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the derivative of a function is its instantaneous slope. And the slope between two points is
$$m=\frac {y_{1}-y_{2}}{x_{1}-x_{2}} $$
The instantaneous slope is conceptually the slope between a point and itself, but we can't quite do this. So instead we must take the slope of the two points: $(x, f (x))$ and $(x+h, f(x+h))$. This yields the slope
$$\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Then to simulate the effect of take taking the slope of "a point and itself" we take the limit as $h\to 0$. Yielding the final equation
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: Technicality: If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, it's also continuous there, which means that $\lim_{h\to0}(x+h,f(x+h))$ is equal to $(x,f(x))$. So you basically wrote the same point twice, and you can't find the slope between a point and itself. Rather, we take the two points $(x,f(x))$ and $(x+h,f(x+h))$, find the slope between them, and _then_ take the limit of the slope as $h$ goes to $0$.

Comment: My bad. Corrected the logic in my answer.